# JLabel from a different class not being drawn

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to show a label from another class. However when I add it to the frame it will not show. I have tried drawing it from the counter class itself by passing in the Frame which I would assume is not good practice (ignoring the fact it didn't work). As well as what is in the code below. Can anybody help me and explain why my solution will not show the created label? As you can most likely tell i'm very new to using JPanel.

```
CookieChaser Class

public class CookieChaser extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie Chaser");
        CookieChaser game = new CookieChaser();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        counter Score = new counter(frame);
        cookie Cookie = new cookie();
        JLabel item = counter.getLabel();
        frame.add(item);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    @Override
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }
}
```

Counter Class

```
public class counter {
    int count;
    static JLabel text;

    public counter(JFrame frame){
        count = 0;
        text = new JLabel(String.valueOf(count));
        text.setLocation(0,0);
        text.setSize(50,50);
    }

    public static JLabel getLabel(){
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: 1) You must add your JLabel to a container. 2) Your paint method does not paint anything. 3) The paint method should be paintComponent instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to create the following Swing GUI.

[image]

Whenever I create a Swing game or application, I use the model / view / controller pattern.  This means I create a GUI model.  The GUI model contains all of the fields that my GUI needs.  Next, I create a GUI view which reads the values from the GUI model.  Finally, I create one or more GUI controllers, which update the GUI model and refresh / repaint the GUI view.

I made the following changes to your code:

1. I created a GUI model.  I created the Counter class.  All the Counter class does is hold a counter value.
2. I created a GUI view, which uses the GUI model.  I created the JFrame, JPanel, and JLabel all in the view class.  You may use more than one class to create the view.  Since this view was simple, I created everything in one class.
3. All Swing applications must start with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  The invokeLater method puts the creation and updating of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Oracle and I insist that all Swing applications start this way.
4. I created a separate Animation runnable so that you can see the JLabel updates.  I increment the counter once a second.
5. The repaint method in the Animation class calls the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to ensure that the JLabel update is done on the Event Dispatch thread.  The animation loop runs in a separate thread to keep the GUI responsive.

Here's the revised code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CookieChaser implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CookieChaser());
    }

    private JLabel counterLabel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cookie Chaser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        counterLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        mainPanel.add(counterLabel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(new Animation(this, counter)).start();
    }

    public void setCounterLabel(String text) {
        counterLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public class Counter {
        private int counter;

        public int getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        public void incrementCounter() {
            this.counter++;
        }
    }

    public class Animation implements Runnable {

        private Counter counter;

        private CookieChaser cookieChaser;

        public Animation(CookieChaser cookieChaser, Counter counter) {
            this.cookieChaser = cookieChaser;
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                counter.incrementCounter();
                repaint();
                sleep(1000L);
            }
        }

        private void repaint() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cookieChaser.setCounterLabel(Integer.toString(counter
                            .getCounter()));
                }
            });
        }

        private void sleep(long duration) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```